# PHP mail() html characters not displaying properly

Tags: php, email, text, unicode, ascii

I am having issues with the PHP mail() function. As you can see below, I am using the PHP mail() function to send HTML e-mails with Chinese characters. While the first e-mail, which sends $studentInfo, displays the text correctly in the final e-mail, the next command, which sends $studentInfoEN, does not display correctly. Any thoughts?

P.S. $name, $phoneNumber, $eMail, etc are all text strings received from an HTML form text input

```
<?php 

$message="<html><body><p>Training Inquiry: ".$_GET["courseName"]."  ".$trainerMonths[$userMonth]." ".$_GET["day"].", 2014 ".$_GET["enLoc"]."</p></body></html>";

$studentInfo="<html><body><p>
                    姓名: $name<br/>
                    电话号码: $phoneNumber <br/> 
                    邮箱: $eMail<br/>
                    工厂名称: $factoryName<br/>
                    WRAP注册编号: $wrapNumber<br/>
                    所在国家: $homeCountry </p></body></html>";

$studentInfoEN="<html><body><p>
    Name $name <br/>
    Phone Number: $phoneNumber <br/>  
    E-mail: $eMail <br/>
    Factory Name: $factoryName <br/>
    WRAP Registration Number: $wrapNumber <br/>
    Home Country: $homeCountry </p></body></html>";

$trainerHeaders = "From:".$email."\n"."Reply-To:".$email."\n"."Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8;"."\n";
$clientHeaders = "From:".$trainerAddress."\n"."Reply-To:".$trainerAddress."\n"."Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8;"."\r\n";

mail($trainerAddress,"Training Inquiry",$message.$studentInfoEN,$trainerHeaders);
mail($eMail,"Web Submission Confirmation","$automatedMessage"."$confirmMessage"."$studentInfo",$clientHeaders); 

?>
```

Comment: email message quotes change between emials

Comment: meaning what? Where are they different?

Comment: Basically, not all programs that are involved here are set to speak the same encoding. This could be anything from your text editor to the user's email program. Maybe this article helps you debug the issue? http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems wrong, you are outputting a string before the opening `<html>` tag and you are closing your `body` and `html` tags on the first line:

```
$studentInfoEN="
    Name"."<html><body><p>$name</p></body></html>"."
```

Should probably just be:

```
$studentInfoEN="<html><body><p>Name: $name
```

**Edit:** Apart from that you are concatenating two messages `$message.$studentInfoEN`, giving you 2 `html` tags, 2 `body`'s etc. which will probably lead to display errors.

Comment: @user2174028 What is the exact problem, how does it not display correctly and could you post the current code under the original code?

Comment: The result from the e-mail is as follows:MIME-Version: 1.0
From: 
Reply-To:
Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8;
<html><body><p>Training Inquiry: fire  January 30, &#050;&#048;&#049;&#052; Dhaka, Bangladesh</p></body></html><html><body><p>
   Name à¦ªà§à¦°à¦¶à¦¿à¦•à§à¦•à¦£ à¦°à§‡à¦œà¦¿à¦¸à§à¦Ÿà§à¦°à§‡à¦¶ <br/>
  Phone Number: 17039451083 <br/>  
  E-mail: russ.jowell@gmail.com <br/>
  Factory Name: à¦ªà§à¦°à¦¶à¦¿à¦•à§à¦•à¦£ à¦°à§‡à¦œà¦¿à¦¸à§à¦Ÿà§à¦°à§‡à¦¶ <br/>
  WRAP Registration Number: 12345678 <br/>
  Home Country: Armenia </p></body></html><br/>This sworks!

Comment: I have added my revised $studentInfoEN in the above section.